# Can't Resolve TabLayout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-support-library

Can't Resolve TabLayout. I have just about every dependency that has been offered as a solution. Project builds, but still can't resolve. I am using androidx, but I also have tried using 28.

Dependencies:

```
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0"
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v7:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.1'
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
        <androidx.core.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

I have changed it to material, I still can't reference TabLayout using a java class.

This is the java code that won't resolve if that helps identify this issue.

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: "I have changed it to material" -- then provide a [mcve] showing the revised layout. For example, perhaps you have a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

In that library, `TabLayout` is [`com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.0.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.java). So, replace the `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` with `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`.

So, for example, I created a scrap project in Android Studio 3.5.1 using the Empty Activity template. I set the `app/build.gradle` to be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.commonsware.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

I can reference `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` from code and layouts without an issue.

Comment: @JarrettWhite: See the updated answer. You might try it yourself, creating a temporary Android Studio project, adding `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` to it, then using `TabLayout` (e.g., create an instance via the constructor in your Java/Kotlin code).

Comment: I have tried that as well, and same issue. Pretty much at a loss at this point. I have gone through all the answers for TabLayout can't resolve. Do i need to import anything into the java class?

Comment: @JarrettWhite: "Do i need to import anything into the java class?" -- you do not have a Java class in your question, so I cannot really answer that.

Comment: Is there an import that is required for TabLayout to be referenced? like is it in appcompat, or is it in another import

Comment: @JarrettWhite: The `import` would be for `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`. `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` is a fully-qualified name of a Java class.

Comment: Please see edit for section of code that won't resolve.

Comment: @JarrettWhite: It would be a lot better if you included the entire Java file, not just some lines from one. Does your file contain `import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;`?

Comment: That would be the necessary import i was asking about before. Thanks for the help it is working now.